# Excel Vlookup changing table array will prompt error

Tags: excel, vlookup

Excel `vlookup` changing table array will prompt error.

This is the current `vlookup` formula that I have:

```
=VLOOKUP($Y4,'C:\Users\Karla\Desktop\Karla\Source Files\User Files\[LD__TEMPLATE_(Master) 2017_Ver 1.0_Updated 24 Sept 2017.xlsx]TNBT METER WEB'!$A$4:$U$514,21,FALSE)
```

Currently, the table array(file) has been changed to a new path:

> C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\After_LD_(Master) 2017_Ver 1.0_Updated

So, I tried to replace the new path and filename with the existing one.

```
=VLOOKUP($Y4,'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\After_LD_(Master) 2017_Ver 1.0_Updated.xlsx]TNBT METER WEB'!$A$4:$U$514,21,FALSE)
```

However, I got an error when I paste the new path and filename.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Why don't you open the file from new location and then refer the table  ?

Comment: I just tried highlighting the table array value and click enter. It prompts for "File" but the moment i click on the new file, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a "[" in the new formula...

I think it should be :
`=VLOOKUP($Y4,'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\[After_LD_(Master) 2017_Ver 1.0_Updated.xlsx]TNBT METER WEB'!$A$4:$U$514,21,FALSE)`